Miracast connection to Samsung CU8572 fails with Latitude E7270
I have installed all firmware and driver updates SupportAssist has suggested (including flashing the latest BIOS), but am failing to connect to a Samsung CU8572 TV (wireless display); all of my other devices can connect easily.
For this laptop, though, the TV just errors out with "[PC name] was unable to connect. Try using your mobile device to connect instead." My other PC with Windows 10 can also connect normally, and it uses an external Wi-Fi adapter. It's just this E7270 that can't connect. The TV and the laptop are connected to the same SSID.
I have tried removing and readding the TV, uninstalling it from Device Manager, nothing.
I have tried searching for duplicates and haven't found any. I have also already asked at Dell Community, but have not yet received an answer.
Edit: I just updated the Intel Wi-Fi driver as well, but still no luck.
